# Key with multiple values

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I am doing a college project where I have multiple values with a key. Here is my code

```
import  java.util.Hashtable;

private Hashtable name2email;
name2email = new Hashtable();

@Override
public void record_user(String name, String email, String address, String phonenumber, double accountnumber, double credit) throws user_exists {
    if (name2email.containsKey(name)||    
        name2email.contains(email)||
        name2email.contains(address)||
        name2email.contains(phonenumber)||
        name2email.contains(credit)||
        name2email.contains(accountnumber)) 
    {
        throw new user_exists();
    }
    name2email.put(name, email,address,accountnumber,phonenumber,credit);
}
```

I am using a HashTable because of the specs of my assignment. Any suggestions? Yes this is the error I am getting back

```
 no suitable method found for put(String,String,String,double,String,double)
    method Hashtable.put(Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Hashtable is obsolete - you can use a HashMap instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash table works with key value pair.

clearly

```
 name2email.put(name, email,address,accountnumber,phonenumber,credit);
```

violates the Hashtable put syntax. Instead you need to be doing something like this

```
name2email.put(name,new User(name,email,address,accountnumber,phonenumber,credit);
```

And your name2email definition should look something like this :

```
Hashtable<String,User> name2email= new Hashtable<String,User>();
```

to check if the record exist you need to do :

```
 User u = name2email.get(name);
 if(u.getName().equals(name) || u.getEmail().equals(email)...(rest of your logic).
  { ...your user exists 
  }
  else put(name,new User(name,email,address,accountnumber,phonenumber,credit);
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a class which contains all these values, instantiate this object and map user name to these "user details" object.

Answer (score 1):

Create a User class (i.e. a domain object), with:

- A field (i.e. member variable) for each data item about a user (name, phone etc.)
- An overridden hashCode() method that computes a hash value based on the data items that represent user identity (can two users have the same name? Same phone number?)
- An overridden equals() method that implements the same identity-ness as hashCode().

In general, if you're using your own classes as Map keys then you want to consider whether the default (i.e. java.lang.Object) hashcode()/equals() methods do what you want (i.e. define identity) correctly.

Implementing hashCode() and equals() correctly is not trivial - read the java.lang.Object API docs carefully for those methods. A decent IDE will implement hashCode() and equals() for you if you tell it which fields to compute those over, which is usually much safer than rolling your own.

Then use a HashMap to map Users to email addresses. (Why's the email address not a member of User? What if a user has multiple email addresses?)

(Prefer HashMap to Hashtable. If you need a thread-safe Map then use ConcurrentHashMap or Collections.synchronizedMap().)